# Converting MP3 file to WAV

Tags: r, audio, mp3, wav

Is it possible to convert a file from .mp3 to .wav in R in order to be able to play the song with R?

Comment: R is not a media player. You can use R for spectrum analysis with various packages, such as [tuneR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuneR/index.html) which [seewave](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/index.html) uses.

Comment: @MO'Connell Some speech recognition softwares, such as CMU Sphinx, only take .wav files as input. This is the situation I am in right now. So the question is not only for misusing R as a media player (which I wouldn't have a problem with either).

Answer (score 8):

Yes (probably). Here's an example:

Converting MP3 to WAV is pretty straightforward:

```
library(tuneR)
r <- readMP3("04 Trip to Paris.mp3")  ## MP3 file in working directory
writeWave(r,"tmp.wav",extensible=FALSE)
```

(to install `tuneR` on Linux, see [here](http://pblog.ebaker.me.uk/2014/07/getting-seewave-r-package-installed-on.html)).

Playback is harder and platform-dependent. `tuneR::play()` tries to use an external player.

- On Windows it tries to guess:

> If under Windows and no
>             player is given, “mplay32.exe” or “wmplayer.exe” (if the
>             former does not exists as under Windows 7) will be chosen as
>             the default.

- On MacOS, specifying `"open"` probably works.
- On Linux, specifying `"play"` probably works *if* you have the `sox` package installed (`sudo apt-get install sox`).

So on my MacOS system

```
tuneR::play("tmp.wav","open")
```

works.

An alternative that does *not* use external resources is `audio::play()`.

```
library(audio)
w <- load.wave("tmp.wav")
play(load.wave("tmp.wav"))
```

It works on MacOS. I don't know if it works on Windows. It does *not* work on my Linux system; `audio` doesn't even install unless you `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev` first, and works poorly even once installed.

(When I say "Linux" here I mean the only system I've tested, Ubuntu 14.04. The `sudo apt-get install ...` incantations I've listed are likely to work on other reasonably recent Debian-based systems, but ... ???)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try to convert it using tuneR!

Comment: How about exporting mp3 files with tuner. is that possible?

Comment: not that I can tell from the docs. `library(sos); findFn("write mp3")` doesn't work either. Maybe post a new question giving more detail about what you want to do?